# SnowSql no response

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-pipe

I am using SnowSql 1.2.5 and I receive no response, no error, absolutely nothing from it.
It does not matter which command I type, even if type just "SnowSql.exe" and hit confirm, I get no response.

This is happening in an specific machine, in others with the same SnowSql version it is working properly.

OS used:
Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit)
Version (Build) 1903 (10.0.18362)

Comment: This can happen for a few reasons, my first suspicion would be something network related - what happens if you try to run SnowCD? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check and confirm if you have already whitelisted the required snowflake endpoints(hosts/ports) for your Snowflake account in the network firewall etc?

You can run the below system function call in your Snowflake account to get the endpoint details specific to your Snowflake account which needs to be whitelisted.

select system$whitelist()

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html

I hope this helps. Let us know if you still see the issue.

Comment: But I have other machines running SnowSql correctly in the same domain. Even for a simple SnowSql --version I get no response. I turned off my local windows firewall and still get the same behaviour.

Comment: Just to give more info, SnowSql does not hang for while, it is like hitting an emtpy command in prompt.

Comment: @Destro This behaviour is similar to what I've seen when there's a network connection issue, but it could also be a shell configuration issue. Can you please run the SnowCD tool I linked above and edit the output into your question?

Comment: Hello, @Hotchips. Plese check the results from SnowCD->  Performing 30 checks for 12 hosts
All checks passed

Comment: @Destro When you say it is like hitting an empty command in prompt, do you mean that Snowsql immediately closes and you go back to the next line in the command prompt? It might be good if you edit the (anonymised) output (or lack thereof) that you're getting into the question.

Comment: @Hotchips I am sorry but I did not understand what you meant